# How do I escape keywords in XML comments like "note"?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, xml-comments

How do I escape keywords in XML comments like "note" in Visual Studio?

e.g.

```
/// See note re Create method attached to this type.
```

I don't want the text after the word "note" to turn blue.

Note this may be a Resharper feature.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Resharper. I thought it was a Visual Studio feature. It  is probably Resharper now you mention it. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know that it's possible. You should ask JetBrains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stop this behaviour by editing your ReSharper options.

Go to `ReSharper -> Options -> Tools -> To-do Items` in Visual Studio, then alter the settings for the 'Note' entry in the patterns box. There are a few things you can do:

- delete the note pattern - this will stop any more occurrences from being highlighted, but will also stop any notes from appearing in the TODO explorer window
- edit the note pattern and untick the comments checkbox - this will stop notes in comments from being highlighted
- edit the note pattern and change the highlight colour to the same colour as for comments - this will stop the highlighting, but will still show the notes in the TODO explorer window

I *suspect* you are not using notes as TODOs, so just deleting the pattern is probably your best option.